# Hidden view from screen are not shown in Bitmap while converting layout to Bitmap

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, android-canvas, android-bitmap

I am creating a Bitmap from the ScrollView layout. Some views are not directly visible. They are visible only when I scroll the ScrollView. These views which are not visible to users without scrolling are not shown in the Bitmap also. The views which are shown to the user are only converted to Bitmap. How to convert the complete layout to Bitmap.

```
            ScrollView marksheetLyt = findViewById(R.id.live_test_marksheet_lyt_id);
            Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(marksheetLyt.getWidth(), marksheetLyt.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
            marksheetLyt.draw(canvas);

            shareMarksheet(bitmap);
```